# Apply the new setup of .vimrc to the file open to the other tab in the terminal

Tags: vimrc

I have two tabs on my terminal. The first one is where I'm doing my project (`html` & `css`). On the other tab I'm working on my `.vimrc`. I added a new plugin (`nerdcommenter`) and it works on the `.vimrc` when I tested it because I also set the following `augroup` inside of it to make sure it will always source the `~/.vimrc`

```
augroup myrefresh
    au!
    au bufwritepost .vimrc source ~/.vimrc
augroup END
```

`nerdcommenter` works on the tab where the `.vimrc` is but it didn't work to other tab where the `html` and `css` located. I tried to run `:e` in the `html` file to test if the `nerdcommenter` functionality will work on it but still it didn't work. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you explain how you « added a new plugin »? Running vim instances typically dont refresh e.g. runtime path or plugin scripts without explicitly being told to. That said, you could try `source $MYVIMRC` to see if that helps.

Comment: I first do `:w` then `:PluginInstall`.

Comment: Overall the question needs more details to help figure out what’s going on and what a solution would look like.

Comment: @muru No, that's a different question because it is about without leaving the `~/.vimrc` while my question is about without leaving the other file opened in vim but on the other tab in the terminal.

Comment: I don't see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The Vim running in the other tab is an entirely separate instance. In order for the changes to be picked up in that tab you will need to source your `.vimrc` there too, by running the following command in that Vim:

```
:source $MYVIMRC
```